# Supporting both ASP.NET Caching and ETag/Conditional GET in WCF WebHttp Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching, rest

I am trying to implement a REST web service with WCF that supports both caching and Conditional GETs.

I implemented basic caching following the instructions in [MSDN: Caching Support for WCF Web HTTP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx). That means adding an `[AspNetCacheProfile("MyOutputCacheProfile")]` attribute to each of my web methods and adding appropriate entries to `web.config`. That seems to work correctly: cached responses are returned when identical arguments are passed to the web methods.

Then I added support for Conditional GET by calculating an ETag value and setting that on the response like this:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetETag(myETag);
```

That sorta works: I can see the `ETag` header in the response the first time I call the web method.

But here's the problem: The next time I invoke that web method with the same arguments, a cached response is returned, and the cached response does not include the `ETag` header.  (If I wait until cache expiration, or disable caching entirely, then the ETag headers are returned properly.)

So, is there any way get the cached responses to include that ETag value?

---

*Update:* After some more study and experimentation, I find that doing this causes the ETag header to be included in all cached responses:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetETag(myETag);
```

If I call that, then I don't need to call the associated `WebOperationContext...SetETag()` operation to make everything work.

Is this the Right Way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong. Restful service are more close to Http and Http caching says that

> The goal of caching in HTTP/1.1 is to eliminate the need to send
>   requests in many cases, and to eliminate the need to send full
>   responses in many other cases. The former reduces the number of
>   network round-trips required for many operations; we use an
>   "expiration" mechanism for this purpose (see section 13.2). The latter
>   reduces network bandwidth requirements; we use a "validation"
>   mechanism for this purpose (see section 13.3).

Asp.net caching does not fall in any one of this category(neither expiration nor validation).The caching is only done on web server and IIS instead of executing the method, sends the stored response. Some how it does not fit in RESTful model.

To implement caching, we should add Cache Control Headers and Etag to response headers and then try to handle conditional Get. Please consult this excellent [article](http://joseoncode.com/2011/04/27/rest-and-the-http-cache-with-wcf-web-api/).